# TensorFlow python 'HParams' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python, tensorflow, magenta

I use tensorflow and magenta from [Google](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/tree/master/magenta/models/sketch_rnn)

When I run the code to train from [sketch_rnn_train](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/models/sketch_rnn/sketch_rnn_train.py#L76) I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sketch_rnn.py", line 135, in <module>
    [train_set, valid_set, test_set, hps_model, eval_hps_model, sample_hps_model] = load_env(data_dir, model_dir)
  File "/root/miniconda2/envs/magenta/lib/python2.7/site-packages/magenta/models/sketch_rnn/sketch_rnn_train.py", line 76, in load_env
    model_params.update(model_config)
AttributeError: 'HParams' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by rolling back to magenta 0.1.13